# use of unresolved identifier 'println' in swift 3

Tags: swift

I'm just a beginner with Swift. I am trying a very basic code, but unable to print things using 'println'.
This is my code,

```
import Cocoa
var myString:String? = nil
if myString != nil {
    println(myString)
}else {
    println("myString has nil value")
}
```

Comment: It's `print` since Swift 2.

Comment: I tried the same code with 'print' instead of 'println'. It worked.!! Thanks @ Martin

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`println()` does not work in xcode. Instead, `print()` function is used to print a statement with a newline.

If instead, you were to want to print without a newline, a `terminator` is used

Try this for your code:

```
import Cocoa
var myString:String? = nil
if myString != nil {
    print(myString)
} else {
    print("myString has nil value")
}
```

Example with terminator:

```
import Cocoa
var myString:String? = nil
if myString != nil {
    print(myString, terminator:"")
} else {
    print("myString has nil value", terminator:"")
}
```

Comment: @paxdiablo Of course. This error would not arise in Swift...